# How to deploy an Eclipse project referencing a sub-project on Heroku?

Tags: java, eclipse, heroku, deployment

I'm working on a Java web project using Heroku as hosting PaaS. As IDE I'm using Eclipse and I'm trying to deploy this project.

In a previous version the project had only Maven dependencies, but now I'm referencing another project as dependency of the main web-app that doesn't reside in the main repository.

Which is the right approach to this case? Should I use a single repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "right" way to do it is making the project you depend on a published artifact in a Maven repository. But that is a pain for small projects.

Here are some other options:

- Build the app locally from your `/.m2/repository` artifacts and deploy with [Heroku Maven plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin)
- Check the JAR file dependency in to Git as an [unmanaged dependency](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies)
- Make the dependency a Maven module in your main project, but also make the module dir a [Git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). That way it's still a separate project but can be [deploy to Heroku as a single app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-submodules).

If you decide to do it the "right" way, I recommend deploying the artifact to [bintray.com](https://bintray.com), which is a little easier to use in this kind of scenario than, say, Sonatype.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll go with the first option, setting the sub-project as a Maven dependency of the main project.